# Unable to enable CiviCase

Tags: civicase, mysql

When I try to enable CiviCase I get a white screen of death and the following msg:

"A fatal error was triggered: Could not create the MySQL views for CiviCase. Your mysql user needs to have the 'CREATE VIEW' permission"

I cannot find any way to add this permission in PhpAdmin. What should I do?

Comment: According to my Control Panel, the MySQL user for the database already has 'CREATE VIEW' permission.

Comment: Oh just saw this. Is it `user@localhost` - the part after the `@` might be significant and needs to match. Also try running a simple test Create View command manually in phpmyadmin and see what error you get.

Comment: See also https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/unable-to-enable-civicase-definer-v-invoker-problem-maybe where the problem was a mismatched user domain.

Answer (score 3):

RESOLVED thanks to help from Hershel:
[Unable to enable CiviCase - Definer v Invoker problem maybe](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/unable-to-enable-civicase-definer-v-invoker-problem-maybe)

The solution was to enable remote connections for the specific MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look in your hosting control panel or ask your hosting provider. The mysql user account may not be allowed to have this permission in your hosting setup.